# Formato de dato double enviado a mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Por ejemplo, ingreso el número "1" en un `JTextField`, luego, antes de enviar el número a la base de datos y hacer el correspondiente Insert, paso el número a double, y el número en la base de datos se ingresa tal como lo ingresé en el `JTextField` (1), y no (1.0). El tipo de dato en mi base de datos es float. He probado de muchísimas formas y aún no lo consigo.

He intentado con:

```
Double.valueOf(JTextField.getText());
```

Y también con:

```
Double.parseDouble(JTextField.getText());
```

También he intentado un montón de validaciones y tampoco me valida.

Comment: Si ingresas directamente 1.0 en el campo, ¿se almacena correctamente?

Comment: Asi es pero no quiero eso, trate muchas validaciones para que el campo ingresado sea 1.0 pero no sirve, excepto a que ingrese un 1.1 que si funciona. es el 0 el que me da problemas.

Comment: Durante el debug, ¿El valueOf o parseDouble están devolviendo el 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la base de datos, para guardar números decimales, se tiene que utilizar el tipo `decimal(x,y)` dónde:

`x` = Cantidad de *Números* a guardar
`y` = Cantidad de *decimales* a guardar

Es importante destacar que si, por ejemplo, definimos un campo cómo `decimal(18,2)` significa que tendrás 16 posiciones de números a la *izquierda* de la coma y 2 posiciones de decimales a la *derecha* de la coma.

Asimismo es importante *analizar* realmente qué tipo de números se van a guardar para intentar acotar al máximo la `(x,y)`.

Por lo que comentas lo has definida como `Decimal(4,1)`; es significa que tu valor máximo va a ser `999.9` (total= 4 posiciones, 3 izquiera, 1 derecha).

Comment: Ahora me queda mas claro, creo que me pase y solo necesito que mi valor maximo sea 9.9  es decir Decimal(1,1);

Comment: Atención! con `Decimal(1,1)` **sólo** podrás guardar 1 posición decimal!! lo que necesitas es `Decimal(2,1)`. 1 decimal y te queda 1 posición de entero.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontre la solucion, y estaba en el campo de la base de datos
Cambie de tipo float a DEC(4,1)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/9587)

Comment: @eferion publica los comentarios en español. Asimismo, no había respuesta por *aceptar* cuando se publicó esta respuesta.

Comment: Ese comentario es el automático que sale en las labores de moderación

Comment: Editado, perdon no conocia esa regla.

Comment: No se por qué a veces salen comentarios de moderación en inglés... faltará alguna traducción